QT Cmake Gstreamer "glib.h no such file or directory" error
I'm developing a project in qt and cmake and I needed to use gstreamer. That's why I downloaded gstreamer. But when I add it to cmake.txt, it gives the error "glib.h no such file or directory". The error appears in the gst.h file
This is my CMakeLists.txt file:
set(GSTREAMER_ROOT_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/mingw_x86_64")
set(GSTREAMER_LIBDIR "${GSTREAMER_ROOT_DIR}/lib")
set(GSTREAMER_INCLUDE_DIRS "${GSTREAMER_ROOT_DIR}/include/gstreamer-1.0")

include_directories(${GSTREAMER_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_link_libraries(VideoTutorial PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Network 
    ${GSTREAMER_LIBRARIES}
)


What am I doing wrong? Thank You.
i installed gstreamer for qt but i cant install.

Did you install the build dependencies for gstreamer? Notably Glib?

Do I need to add all dependencies one by one?

Yes. At which point people switch to grabbing their dependencies from a proper packaging system (like conan or vcpkg) since that is a solved problem.
